# Why can't I click on a tkinter entry after touching an embedded Panda3D window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, panda3d

I am writing a tkinter application that contains a Panda3D window. However, I have found that when I click on or interact with the Panda3D window, I am then unable to click on any tkinter Entry widget. If I select out of the tk window and then select it again, The Entry widgets work again. Why is this happening?

Code to reproduce:

```py
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from panda3d.core import WindowProperties
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button, Entry

from multiprocessing import Process


class AppTk(ShowBase):

    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self, windowType='none')
        self.startTk()

        self.tk = self.tkRoot
        self.tk.geometry("500x400")

        self.label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.tk, text='Panda3D Example', width=420, height=340)
        self.label_frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.tk, text='Click me !', bd='5')
        self.button.pack()

        self.entry = Entry(self.tk)
        self.entry.pack()

        # Set properties of the Panda3D window
        props = WindowProperties()
        props.set_parent_window(self.label_frame.winfo_id())  # Display within the label frame
        props.set_origin(10, 20)  # Relative to the label frame
        props.set_size(400, 300)

        self.make_default_pipe()
        self.open_default_window(props=props)

        scene = self.loader.load_model("environment")
        scene.reparent_to(self.render)

app = AppTk()
app.run()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVr8a.png)